# Correct PHP syntax to pass values to HTTP meta refresh?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

The context where I intend to use a meta refresh does not require me to be concerned with the back button, security, crawlers, response codes nor any best practices that generally recommend not using HTTP meta refresh. I do not want to use client-side script.

Note this is WordPress. The incorrect results suggest I do not have the correct PHP syntax and that is the question I am asking: what is the correct syntax to enable the following meta refresh to function as expected...

```php
<?php
$scrnD_refresh_duration = 2;
$scrnD_refresh_url = 'http://wordpress.org';

add_action('wp_head', 'scrnD_add_meta_refresh');
function scrnD_add_meta_refresh() {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="'. $scrnD_refresh_duration .'; url='. $scrnD_refresh_url .'">';
}
?>
```

// echo displays the values as expected...

```php
echo $scrnD_refresh_duration; // displays 2
echo $scrnD_refresh_url;      // displays http://wordpress.org
```

// Hardcoded values refresh as expected...

```php
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2; url=http://wordpress.org">';
```

// View source shows the function generates this with no values...

```php
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="; url=">
```

What's the correct syntax to be used in the function?

Answer (score 3):

A function in PHP has its own “scope”, meaning that it has its own set of variables that is independent of those outside of the function.

That’s why `$scrnD_refresh_duration` and `$scrnD_refresh_url` are empty within your function: They have never been defined there. The definitions *outside* of the function don’t apply.

For cases like these, PHP offers the `global` statement that “pulls in” variables from the global scope. Use it like this:

```
function scrnD_add_meta_refresh() {
    global $scrnD_refresh_duration, $scrnD_refresh_url;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue of variable scope. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php.

Your function is referencing locally scoped variables, $scrnD_refresh_duration and $scrnD_refresh_url that do not hve a value inside the function. You could pass in values to your function, then reference them that way.

```
function scrnD_add_meta_refresh($conent, $url) {
...
```